# Is it possible to save the ventboy?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've played the demo for Mass Effect 3 and was a tad upset when the ventboy died. I was wondering if there was a certain choice that actually lets you convince him to come with you?

I had put my game on action for the story experience but would definitely go back if saving him was a possibility. During the full game my character had a nightmare about him and I found it interesting yet dumb as far as the story part of this game goes.

Comment: The nightmare is the low point of ME3. Apart from all the ways they've maimed gameplay, i mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played the demo and the full game with different choices, and there's no choice that gives you a way to save the little boy in the vent.  Sadly, he is destined to die no matter what choices you make.

I believe he's there for the "shock factor" and to raise the stakes of the introductory sequence.  They want you to have a more "personal" connection to the invasion of Earth, rather than just watching a bunch of futuristic buildings get lazer'ed.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the way the situation resolves before the end of that chapter I'm fairly certain you cannot.

> What with both the shuttles being destroyed by Reapers and all.

I think the point of it, from a story point of view is to give Shepard something else to be traumatized about (especially since they take some asking about how traumatized you are in the "I don't have a save game" character creation).

I've now had the opportunity to play out both of the choices and as far as keeping ventboy alive goes, neither is effective.

Additionally, based on more gameplay

> The boy is not real but is being implanted in Shepard's mind to mess with him.  He appears at the end of the game as part of the final decision sequence.

Comment: Thanks, i figured since i jumped right into it i might've made a bad choice in doing so, And i thought since they focused so much on him you might be given an option.

Comment: @SmashinMuffinz No problem, I think it's more of attaching a sentimental emotion to Earth/Innocence ... and a "those bastards" when he dies ...

Answer (score 0):

His existence is just for shock value, and there's a good chance that he is a figment of Shepard's imagination.